# PouchDB not detecting sqlite plugin using cordova

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, pouchdb

I recently used **PouchDB** to get an easy way of developing through mobile phone but it seems there's a bit problem when I'm trying to deploy it on a mobile phone. You see, our data will contain a huge amount so the only option here is to use sqlite plugin for database instead of websql or indexeddb. So I tried the example provided by the documentation and it worked pretty well. But when I console.log(pouch.adapter) it says "websql". I tried browsing for the database using eclipse but there was nothing there. ***How can I force pouchdb to use sqlite always?*** Thanks!

**Tldr;** tried deploying pouchDB with sqlite plugin but instead it used websql. trying to force pouchDB to use sqlite all the time.

Comment: Have you tried asking it to the developrs itself? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pouchdb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I responded in the Google Groups, but basically `db.adapter` will report "websql" whether it's using WebSQL or the SQLite plugin. Kinda confusing, sorry about that!

**Update**: as of PouchDB 3.4.0, you can call `db.info().then(console.log.bind(console))` and print out the database info, and it will report `sqlite_plugin` true or false. Makes debugging easier. :)

Comment: In the thread you say "If you see *.db files being created inside your app's directory, then yes. :)" [that verifies your adapter is using sqlite]. Can you give an example path that indicates which files you're talking about? I'm not sure what to look for in my path.

Comment: On Android it's /data/data/com.company.appname/databases

Comment: @nlawson hi, i am using angularjs & cordova for my application. I have imported js files in the following order.  cordova, ng-cordova, sqllite.js, pouchdb.js. Still, i am getting sqlite_plugin:false. do you have any idea?

Comment: @yokks I'm also having the same issue (using ionic framework). Did you manage to resolve?

Comment: @JamesJ hi, i am on deadline. rightnow, i moved to cordova instead of ng-cordova. i have to find the way later. if you find , plz do let me know.

Comment: cordova probably doesn't expose `window.sqlitePlugin`, which is what PouchDB is looking for. just a hunch.

Comment: @nlawson is there a way to make it expose it?

Comment: I don't know. You'd have to check https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin/

Comment: @yokks I solved the issue by adding a CSP to index.html as per https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist hope that helps.

Comment: @JamesJ i havent tried CSP before. Can you share it?

Comment: @yokks You need to set rules as per the docs but as I'm not loading any external content this works for me (added to index.html) `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">`

Comment: Turns out this didn't fix it. I looks like the plugin is loaded correctly, when I log `window.sqlitePlugin.echoTest();` inside of device ready I get isSqlLitePlugin: true but the pouchDB `db.info().then(console.log.bind(console));` gives me `sqllite_plugin: false`. Nightmare.

Comment: if `window.sqlitePlugin` is available at the moment you load PouchDB, then it will use the SQLite Plugin. So you have to order your `script` tags correctly. Also please make sure you're using PouchDB 3.4.0 or later.

Answer (score 0):

One of the latest versions have had a bug and pouchdb was not using sqllite.
You can see more here: https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/3505

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you install this plugin

`cordova plugin add https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage`

and the use this in your JS script

`var db = new PouchDB('new_puchDB', {adapter : 'websql'});`

ensure that the plugin was installed correctly and your cordova versions is 3.0+ (works with latest -- I'm using it as we speak)

Comment: My need is to use pouchdb with sqlite plugin. I have an ionic application, with pouchdb installed. I also have cordova-sqlite-storage plugin installed from https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin. When i run 'db.info().then(console.log.bind(console))', it gives me** sqlite_plugin: false** . The order of file inclusion in my index.html is ng-cordova.js, cordova.js, pouchdb.js. Do we need to include SQLite.js as well ?

Comment: Of course. Make sure the plugin is loaded in Cordova. Check cordova_plugins.js and make sure all is installed.

Check the `clobber` object and write the name of the variable in your console to make sure it exists